# Timer Update for images using as3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to update images through a timer. I only can upload one image at time. If i were to remove the image and upload another image. Then my app should update to most current image real time. For some reason it is not reading my newUpdate functions. "newUpdate" function should compare the xml then reload image if xml file don't match. I need assistance on my update function. Maybe my logic for the update functions is wrong, any help would be appreciated. Thank you

```
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var xmlData:XML;
var imageList:XMLList;
var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var imageIndex:uint = 0;
var child:DisplayObject;
var timer:Timer =new Timer(3000,0);
var myImageHolder = new ImageHolder();

addChild(myImageHolder);
myImageHolder.x= 0;
myImageHolder.y= 0;

function newUpdate(e:TimerEvent) {
      if (imageList != xmlData.sectionItem.file) {
    newScreensaver();
    } 
}

function newScreensaver() {
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest(path +"metv.xml"));
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);
addChild(videoTxt);
}

function xmlLoaded(e:Event) {
xmlData = new XML ( e.target.data);
imageList = xmlData.sectionItem.file;
loadImage(path + imageList[0]);
}

function imageLoaded(e:Event){
child = myImageHolder.addChild(imageLoader);
}

function loadImage(path:String){
imageLoader.load(new URLRequest( path));
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,imageLoaded);
}
```

Comment: if (currentImage != (path + imageList[0]))
  loadImage(path + imageList[0]);
    currentImage = path + imageList[0];.... i just had to add a new variable and specify the string.. and then compare current image to the new path... thank for all of your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you have given enough context to answer the question, because the line:

```
if (imageList != xmlData.sectionItem.file)
```

Will never yeild true because of the line:

```
imageList = xmlData.sectionItem.file;
```

Please explain at what point and why either xmlData or imageList will change value after the initial XML data is loaded.

...maybe that is the problem?

Comment: you are correct and that was the problem... it was not specific enough... that is the code that looks for the image tag in the xml file... instead i need compare string that is already uploaded....it works now.... thank you...

Answer (score 0):

For the very first time, both `imageList` and `xmlData` are `null`. They neither instantiated not assigned. So both are equal at that moment, the `newScreensaver()` won't execute because of your condition.

My suggestion is to load the `xml` very first, once it's done loading start loading the images and save it. If you done so, you will reuse(`clone`) it and you don't have to wait for the image getting loaded everytime. Once all the images are loaded start your timer. If you are having more number of images then start your timer after a few(say 3 or 5) images finished loading.

Note: Assumed you are having a xml file with all image names(say 5 images name/path) and loading the same images one by one repeatedly.